# MYSQL Select As Case when number of rows statement

Tags: mysql, select, case-when

I'm trying to find the number of notifications for each user, I am having a little problem, I had the query working perfect for what I needed it for, then I changed my table around just a little bit.

Working query:

```
$numNotifications = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("
SELECT  
      N.*, 
      P.*
      FROM 
          notifications N, 
          posts P
      WHERE 
          N.userID='$session' 
      AND 
          (
          N.action='1' OR N.action='2'
          ) 
      AND 
           N.uniqueID=P.id AND  P.state='0'"
));
```

However, uniqueID is now different for some rows. when N.aciton is "1" then N.uniqueID should be compared to P.id, however when N.action is "2" it should compare a row in that table with P.id.

Example query, (that SHOULD work, but doesn't)

```
$numNotifications = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("
SELECT  
      N.*, 
      P.*, 
      C.*, 
     (CASE WHEN (
                  N.action = 2 AND N.state = 0
                 )
            THEN 
                 C.postID ELSE N.uniqueID END
      ) AS postId  
      FROM 
          notifications N, 
          posts P, 
          comments C 
      WHERE 
          N.userID='$session' 
      AND 
          (
          N.action='1' OR N.action='2'
          ) 
      AND 
           postId=P.id AND  P.state='0'"
));
```

diagram of my 3 table structures:

http://i41.tinypic.com/nyzolg.png

Comment: hello again :) you mean when action=1, uniqueID points to a post (P.id), and when action=2, uniqueID points to a comment (C.id)?

Comment: Well, when action=1 P.id and N.uniqueID are the same. Same as when action=2 C.id and N.unique are the same, if you follow how I have this set up?

Comment: yes, i follow :) but this is not what you've written in this question. between the code examples you write P.id twice, instead of P.id/N.id. that's why i was asking for clearification! i believe you're making things more difficult with this notifications-table actually. it only holds redundant data.

Comment: i take that back.. you keep track of two things: 1) has the user been notified of the new post/comment? 2) has the user read the new post/comment? is this correct?

Comment: Well honestly I've just confused myself with this, I'm trying to figure out right now what exactly I'm trying to do lol. As far as the data it holds, it's mostly necessary for my website that I'm building, (some of it will be used in the future)

Comment: well, any rows in the database alone means the user has been notified, the column "state" means whether it's unread or read. (unread 0, read 1) and that applies through all my tables with that row.

Comment: I think one of the problems is that it's merging the data between tables. So when i call N.userID, instead of it just calling it from notifications table, it calls it from any other table I have specified in the query, so comments and posts table. because they also use userID for columns. I'm not sure how to straighten this out. Even when i specify N.userID it seems to go into other tables still.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6533/discussion-between-davogotland-and-dylan-cross)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go :)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(`notif_id`) AS `number_of_new_notifications`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            `notifications`.`id` AS `notif_id`
        FROM
            `notifications`
        JOIN
            `posts`
        ON
            `notifications`.`uniqueID`=`posts`.`id`
        WHERE
            `notifications`.`userID`='$session'
        AND
            `notifications`.`action`=1
        AND
            `notifications`.`state`=0
        AND
            `posts`.`state`=0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            `notifications`.`id` AS `notif_id`
        FROM
            `notifications`
        JOIN
            `comments`
        ON
            `notifications`.`uniqueID`=`comments`.`id`
        JOIN
            `posts`
        ON
            `comments`.`postID`=`posts`.`id`
        WHERE
            `notifications`.`userID`='$session'
        AND
            `notifications`.`action`=2
        AND
            `notifications`.`state`=0
        AND
            `comments`.`state`=0
        AND
            `posts`.`state`=0
    ) AS notification_ids;
```